# $\forall B \subset Y (f(f^{-1}(B))=B)$ $\implies$ $f$ is surjective

Tags: analysis, functions

$f:X\to Y$, where $X, Y$ are sets.

I need to prove:

$\forall B\subseteq Y,\,(f(f^{-1}(B))=B)\implies f$ is surjective

My approach:

Let's take $B=Y$:

$$\begin{align}f(f^{-1}(Y))&=\{y\,|\,\exists x\in f^{-1}(Y):y=f(x)\}\\&=\{y\,|\,\exists x\in X:y=f(x)\}\end{align}$$

And this is equal to $Y$ which implies $\forall y\in Y,\,\exists x\in X:y=f(x)$ which is a definition of a surjective function $\square$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, thank you for an answer. I think no, because I want to check my approach and if it is not correct, to see the right answer.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: If $f$ is not injective then there are potential problems with saying $f^{-1}(Y)=X$, no? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @FShrike No, there is no problem whatsoever, since $f^{-1}(Y)$ is the preimage of $Y$, which exists for every function.

Comment: So, preimage is defined in a multivalued sense? As in the preimage of $[-1,1]$ under sine wouldn't just return some distinct set of points, it would return the entire real line? I only am thrown by this since taking $\arcsin[-1,1]$ could give any number of things, depending on the branch @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The set $f^{-1}(Y)$ is simply $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in Y\}$. And $\arcsin\bigl([-1,1]\bigr)=\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. On the other hand, $\sin^{-1}\bigl([-1,1]\bigr)=\Bbb R$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you! I have never ever seen it written anywhere else that there is a nuanced difference between an inverse function of $f$, call it $g$, and what is described by $f^{-1}$! So $g(f(x))=y$ does not necessarily imply $x=y$, but $f^{-1}(f(x))$ notationally means all the values $y$ such that $f(y)=f(x)$?

Comment: Almost. I fact,$$f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)=\{y\in X\mid f(y)=f(x)\}.$$But $f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$ only makes since when $f$ has in inverse.

Comment: Thank you all for answering!